# Exclude span from parsing with requests-html

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, python-requests-html

I need help with parsing a web page with Python and requests-html lib. Here is the `<div>` that I want to analyze:

```
<div class="answer"><span class="marker">А</span>Te<b>x</b>t</div>
```

It renders as:

> Te**x**t

I need to get `Te<b>x</b>t` as a result of parsing, without `<div>` and `<span>` but with `<b>` tags.

Using `element` as a requests-html object, here is what I am getting.

```
element.html:
<div class="answer"><span class="marker">А</span>Te<b>x</b>t</div>

element.text:
ATe\nx\nt

element.full_text:
AText
```

Could you please tell me how can I get rid of `<span>` but still get `<b>` tags in the parsing result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate it.

How about some simple string processing and get the string between two boundaries:

- Use `element.html`
- take everything after the close `</span>`
- Take everything before the close `</div>`

Like this

```
myHtml = '<div class="answer"><span class="marker">А</span>Te<b>x</b>t</div>'

myAnswer = myHtml.split("</span>")[1]
myAnswer = myAnswer.split("</div>")[0]

print(myAnswer)
```

output:

```
Te<b>x</b>t
```

Seems to work for your sample provided. If you have more complex requirements let us know and I'm sure someone can adapt thus further.